# Import WordPress sitemaps into Django sitemaps

Tags: python, django, wordpress, sitemap, django-sitemaps

I am trying to refer to the WordPress blog through my sub domain.  example -

> blog.example.com

WordPress is hosted on GoDaddy

My main app (main domain) is on Django (hosted on Heroku). Have site maps set up on Django apps as well under:

> example.com/site maps.xml

How do I integrate the two sitemaps so that when I go to example.com/site maps.xml I should see sitemaps from both? Is there a way?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate". You could copy paste the wordpress site_maps.xml the Django one. Could you be more specific?

Comment: wordpress blog sitemap is for subdomain blog.example.com. It creates sitemap at blog.example.com/stemap.xml. django is on main domain. www.example.com. It creates its sitemap at www.example.com/sitemaps.xml . how will I specify one sitemap for google webcrawler so that I can crawl both the sitemaps and I can get SEO advantage from subdomain for my master domain.